# bootstrap tab with address? not hashmark?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, tabs, navbar

I want to give each tab a unique address that a user can bookmark.

I also want to load the tab's contents through ajax or, load the whole page when user click on the tab.

Should I use a navigation bar in bootstrap?
Is it supposed to be only one navigation bar in a page?
navbar, nav, tab.. I'm utterly confused with similar concepts, and don't now where to look.
Should I look at the bootstrap source when I feel the doc is not enough?

and.. What should I use here?

Answer (score 0):

For setting the URL shown in the browser window, If you're OK using HTML5, check out the [History Manipulation API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/API/DOM/Manipulating_the_browser_historyy), specifically the `replaceState()` method.

You'll then need to route server-side based on the provided URL. There's a [complete example on Mozilla's site](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/API/DOM/Manipulating_the_browser_history/Example?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=Web%2FGuide%2FDOM%2FManipulating_the_browser_history%2FExample) in PHP, likely adaptable to whatever you're using.